# Cannot get data to span correct number of columns

Tags: html, angular, html-table, col

I am creating a table in HTML. I want to use `colspan` to span across all columns. I am creating this table using several different `ngIf` statements.

I followed the suggestions in other posts by including the `width` but it did not work either.

My html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<br>
<div *ngIf="finalData.length>0">
    <p>User:<strong> {{ourUser}}</strong> </p>

    <div *ngIf="Error1; else Error1">
        <p> It appears that this user cannot be found on Platform 1, so we cannot display any user information.</p>
    </div>

    <ng-template #noError1>
        <div>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"> Platform 1</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>ID1</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>ID2</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th <th>Platform 1</th>
                        <td>{{finalData[0].name}}</td>
                        <td>{{finalData[0].id1}}</td>
                        <td>{{finalData[0].userEmail}}</td>
                        <td>{{finalData[0].userID}}</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                    <div *ngIf="Error2; else noError2">
                        <tr>
                            <th <th>Platform 2</th>
                            <tdcolspan="5" width="100"> It appears that this user cannot be found</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>

                    <ng-template #noError2>
                        <tr>
                            <th <th>Platform 2</th>
                            <td>{{finalData[1].name}}</td>
                            <td>{{finalData[1].id1}}</td>
                            <td>{{finalData[1].userEmail}}</td>
                            <td>Not Listed</td>
                            <td>{{status}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>

                    <div *ngIf="Error3; else noError3">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Platform 3</th>
                            <td colspan="5"> It appears that this user cannot be found on Platform 3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    <ng-template #noError3>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Platform 3</th>
                            <td>{{finalData[2].name}}</td>
                            <td>{{finalData[2].id1}}</td>
                            <td>{{finalData[2].userEmail}}</td>
                            <td>{{finalData[2].userID}}</td>
                            <td>N/A</td>

                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div *ngIf="Error4; else noError4">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <ng-template #noError4>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th <th>Platfrom </th>
                                <th <th>Number of Active IDs</th>
                                <th <th>User ID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th <th>plat</th>
                            <td> {{plat}}</td>
                            <td> {{platID}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th <th>cat</th>
                            <td> {{cat}}</td>
                            <td> {{catID}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>

    </ng-template>
    <br>

    <button (click)='onBack()' id='back'>
        <span>Back to Results</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I want something that looks like

```
|           |            |            |            |            |           | 
|User Info. |            It appears that this user cannot be found.         |
|           |            |            |            |            |           |
```

Instead I am getting

```
|           |            |            |            |            |           | 
|User Info. |It appears  |                                                  |
            |that this   |                                                  |
            |user cannot |                                                  |
            |be found.   |                                                  |                      
|           |            |            |            |            |           |
```

Otherwise the table works as expected.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kjb8c)

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a colspan of `2` for the first column? Or you could insert an empty column.

Comment: Why would it be 2 and not 1? This did not change the outcome.

Comment: Is that row even _in_ a table then?

Comment: Yes it is in a table. I perform an ngIf to check to see if I have the data that belongs in the 5 cells. If I do, I can fill them in. If not then I want to print 'It appears that this user cannot be found.' Everything works as expected except of the message being printed across all five cells instead of one.

Comment: you can add an empty <td> to create an empty cell. The second problem is it seems to fit in one cell instead of 5 cell, but I run your code didn't find anything like that. would you please share your whole code related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It is actually super easy. You can't wrap your table rows in a `div`.

```
<tr *ngIf="Error2; else noError2">
    <th>Platform 2</th>
    <td colspan="5"> It appears that this user cannot be found on Platform 2.</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the div here:

```
<div *ngIf="Error3; else noError3">
```

use `<ng-container>` which will be not included in the DOM and virtually not harmful to the table structure:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="Error3; else noError3">
```